# How to prevent js/css caching in IIS

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis

Am developing a website in asp. So as of now as it is development time I don't want to cache my js/css as it will be undergoing changes.

But after deployment it is better to have caching as it is a longer run process.

Is there a single setting to accomplish this, preferably in IIS server.So whenever I need to take a fresh copy I just enable the setting in IIS

This has been a bottleneck for us as I need to instruct my client to do a cache clearing. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Change the URL of css and js every time.Browser detects a different url and will not load the cached stylesheet/JS. You can change URL by simply adding random query string at end of URL.

```
http://mysite/style.css?Version=1
http://mysite/file.js?Version=1
```

Comment: But what if i want caching. I need to change code.
Is there any setting in IIS

Comment: Just remove the random query string from URL before making live. IF URL not change then browser will load the cache content.

Comment: @Robert_Junior Whenever the content of a file changes the version (timestamp, hash, random number) has to be modified. Therefore it will be safe to cache http://mysite/style.css?Version=1 because will never change, if style.css will be modified the link will become http://mysite/style.css?Version=2, http://mysite/style.css?Version=3 and so on and browser will load the new content. You may want to look at bundling too.